# Python .pop() different behaviour while combining expressions

Tags: python, list

I encountered some strange behavior while using lists in python.

My code is

```
    input_data = open('day_3_input.txt', 'r').read()
    instructions = input_data.split('\n')
    print(len(instructions))
```

The output for this is

```
3
```

To remove the unwanted element at the end, I do a pop()

```
    input_data = open('day_3_input.txt', 'r').read()
    instructions = input_data.split('\n')
    instructions.pop()
    print(len(instructions))
```

As expected output is

```
2
```

But if i run

```
    input_data = open('day_3_input.txt', 'r').read()
    instructions = input_data.split('\n').pop()
    print(len(instructions))
```

My output is

```
0
```

What is the reason for this different behaviour?

Comment: `x = thing; x.method()` means something completely different from `x = thing.method()`.

Comment: `pop` returns the removed element, not the remaining list

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yeah, i got confused with difference between objects and primitive data types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take care of the `pop()` method has a return value.

- `pop()` parameters

The pop() method takes a single argument (index).

The argument passed to the method is optional. If not passed, the default index -1 is passed as an argument (index of the last item).

If the index passed to the method is not in range, it throws IndexError: pop index out of range exception.

- The `pop()` method returns the item present at the given index. This item is also removed from the list.

So if you run

```py
  input_data = open('day_3_input.txt', 'r').read()
  instructions = input_data.split('\n').pop()
  print(len(instructions))
```

`instructions` is equal to the last element of the split `input_data` array.

Thus, it will print the length of the last element of the split `input_data` array rather than the length of the split `input_data` array.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the items included in the `instruction` variable after splitting the file content on `\n`. You'll probably see `''` and the end of your list. So, when you `pop()` it, you'll get the last item of the list (in this case `''`, clearly with the length of `0`). Whereas in the former, you have a list with 3 items at first, and poping one item results in a modified list with 2 items.

BTW, in the latter form, you are putting just one item into your `instruction` variable (output of `pop()`).